# Restructure Dataset

Tags: r, data-manipulation, reformat

I've been working for 4 hours to try to format a dataset.

Here is the structure of the original dataset.

```
Subject_ID | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 

1. 

2. 

3. 

4. 

5.
```

I'd like to make it the following format

```
Subject_ID | Task | A | B | 

1. (under subject column)           1 (under Task Column)

1.  (under subject column)          2 (under Task Column)

1.   (under subject column)         3 (under Task Column)

1.   (under subject column)         4 (under Task Column)

1.   (under subject column)         5 (under Task Column)

2.   (under subject column)         1 (under Task Column)

2.    (under subject column)        2 (under Task Column)

2.    (under subject column)        3 (under Task Column)

2.    (under subject column)        4 (under Task Column)

2.    (under subject column)        5 (under Task Column)
```

I have tried the following code, which formats the data correctly, but does not create the Task column that is based off of the numbers in the original datasets column names.

```
setDT(test)
test <- melt(test, id.vars = c("Subject_ID"),  
         measure = patterns('A', 'B'), 
         value.name = c('a', 'b', 'skin_conductance'))[, variable := NULL] 
[order(Subject_ID)]
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what your data look like. Consider using `dput()` to share a sample of your data.

Comment: @OTStats, yes my apologies. I can't figure out how to properly format it as I'm new

Comment: Type `dput(my_dataframe_name)` and update your question with what it tells you